# How to aggregate value of inner array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My Document Structure:

```
{"id"   : 1
    "apps" : [
        {
            "name" : "APP1",
            "date_added" : Timestamp(1453470861, 1),
            "power" : [
                {
                    "date" : Timestamp(1453470960, 1),
                    "amount" : 30.3739953125
                },
                {
                    "date" : Timestamp(1453470960, 1),
                    "amount" : 30.3739953125
                },
                {
                    "date" : Timestamp(1453470960, 1),
                    "amount" : 30.3739953125
                },
                {
                    "date" : Timestamp(1453470967, 1),
                    "amount" : 30.30951765625
                }
        }]
}
```

I have multiples apps in the document but only posted one.

I want to group by apps.name and get the sum of power.amount for each app.
This is the code that I came up with:

```
db.x.aggregate([{$match:{id:1}},{$unwind:"$apps"},{$group:{_id:"$apps.name",total:{$sum:"$apps.power.amount"}}}])
```

But I get this as the result:

```
{ "_id" : "APP1", "total" : 0 }
```

Could someone tell me what causes the query to give zero as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to $unwind the "power" before count it.

this is my proposal :

```
db.x.aggregate([{$match:{id:1}},{$unwind:"$apps"},{$unwind:"$apps.power"},{$group:{_id:"$apps.name",total:{$sum:"$apps.power.amount"}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

## MongoDB version 3.2 or newer solution:

After the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage the next stage is the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage where you basically use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) to return 2d array of "amount". From there you need to denormalize the 2d array using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator. The last stage in the pipeline is another [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage where you use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator operator  *available in the `$group` and `$project` stages starting from version 3.2* to calculate the total sum of "amount".

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "id": 1 } }, 
        { "$project": { 
            "amounts": { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": "$apps",
                    "as": "app", 
                    "in": { 
                        "$map":  { 
                            "input": "$$app.power", 
                            "as": "p", 
                            "in": "$$p.amount" 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }}, 
        { "$unwind": "$amounts" }, 
        { "$project": { "total": { "$sum": "$amounts" } } }  
    ]
)
```

Which yields:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a54de01964fd33b12ccaab"), "total" : 121.43150359375 }
```